# IndexOf Javascript alternative

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm trying to do an indexof function. but we're not allowed to use it, or any build-in function in javascript. so i create my own. I upload it in our tester but there's only one condition that I didn't met. Thanks!

here's my code :

```
function indexofmyversion(searchChar,index) {
var a="";
for(var i=0; i<=searchChar.length; i++){
   if(searchChar[i] == index){
       return i;
    } 
} return -1; }
```

[image: Tester Picture Result]

Comment: 3 arguments are being given. You are using 2.

Comment: A third argument is missing in your function, `fromIndex`.

Comment: So, you failed on one part; what part was that? Explain the problem in your question, don't just link to, or show, a picture and expect that to suffice as your 'question.' Why did you fail? How did you attempt to correct that failure? What do you need help with, what went wrong?

Comment: See MDN, [*Array.prototype.indexOf()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which includes a POJS implementation as a polyfill. You don't have to copy it, but it might give you some ideas. The index is a *from* index, not a *to* index.

Answer (score 5):

The test failed due to fact that the searching should start from index 4 , simply add another parameter as required

```
function indexofmyversion(searchChar,index, fromIndex) {
var a="";
for(var i=fromIndex; i<searchChar.length; i++){
   if(searchChar[i] == index){
       return i;
    } 
} return -1; }
```

Comment: i < searchChar.length

Comment: @lazyvab oh , u are right , i copied OP's code and added required improvements didnt notice this,  thanks

Comment: @NinaScholz what do you mean?

Comment: too much variables.

Comment: @NinaScholz well its Op's code i just added what is needed to pass test..